# regex Match a capture group's items only once

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to split a string in several options, but those options are allowed to occur only once. I've figured out how to make it match all options, but when an option occurs twice or more it matches every single option.

Example string: `--split1 testsplit 1 --split2 test split 2 --split3 t e s t split 3 --split1 split1 again`

Regex: `/-{1,2}(split1|split2|split3) [\w|\s]+/g`

Right now it is matching all cases and I want it to match `--split1`, `--split2` and `--split3` only once (so `--split1 split1 again` will not be matched).

I'm probably missing something really straight forward, but anyone care to help out? :)

**Edit**:

Decided to handle the extra occurances showing up in a script and not through RegEx, easier error handling. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're missing the obvious _don't try and make RegEx do what ain't RegEx' job ..._

Comment: Just add unique occurrences to the output array.

Comment: @CBroe As I wasn't sure if RegEx was able to do this I had to ask ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Alright will do, thanks

Comment: Note you could use a negative lookahead to get the *last* occurrences only, but you only need the first one as far as I can see. To do that, you need an infinite width lookbehind that is only available in .NET regex (and PyPi Python regex).

Comment: I need all 3 options, so: `--split1`, `--split2` and `--split3` but I only want them to match only once. So if any of the options occur twice or more in the string , I just want the first one of those options

Comment: You may do it with .NET/Python PyPi regex. Just checked: both answers below are wrong, BTW. But I guess you are using JavaScript, right?

Comment: While stuff like this often can be done in RegEx somehow (like create patterns matching all possible orders, and join them together as possible alternatives), this usually gets quite messy. If at all possible (i.e., if you are not limited to using _only_ RegEx), then let RegEx do the pattern matching part to get the individual option/value pairs - and leave the rest up to your following script logic that operates on those found matches. [...]

Comment: [...] That also makes it easier to be precise in the error messages you might want to issue to a caller - you can specifically tell me that I accidentally specified `--split2` twice, rather than "input did not match ^(mo|nst|er|pat|tern)$, error, does not compute, beep beep bupp"

Comment: @CBroe There is one "but" : if the regex is used in some tool where you have no access to the code itself, it becomes impossible to use things like `.Distinct()`, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, now that you put it like that it makes quite a bit more sense to handle it in the script itself. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @wesley221 But where is your script? Without it, your question is off-topic.

Comment: Do you need any help? If not, just remove the post as it can only be answered by you, or please edit it to include the code that does not work.

Comment: Edited the OP with some clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Somehow I ended up here from the PHP section, hence the PHP code. The same principles apply to any other language, however.

---

I realise that OP has said they have found a solution, but I am putting this here for future visitors.

```php
function splitter(string $str, int $splits, $split = "--split")
{
    $a = array();
    for ($i = $splits; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if (strpos($str, "$split{$i} ") !== false) {
            $a[] = substr($str, strpos($str, "$split{$i} ") + strlen("$split{$i} "));
            $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "$split{$i} "));
        }
    }

    return array_reverse($a);
}
```

This function will take the string to be split, as well as how many segments there will be. Use it like so:

```
$array = splitter($str, 3);
```

It will successfully explode the array around the `$split` parameter.
The parameters are used as follows:

- `$str`
  The string that you want to split. In your instance it is: `--split1 testsplit 1 --split2 test split 2 --split3 t e s t split 3 --split1 split1 again`.
- `$splits`
  This is how many elements of the array you wish to create. In your instance, there are 3 distinct splits.
  If a split is not found, then it will be skipped. For instance, if you were to have `--split1` and `--split3` but no `--split2` then the array will only be split twice.
- `$split`
  This is the string that will be the delimiter of the array. Note that it must be as specified in the question. This means that if you want to split using `--myNewSplit` then it will append that string with a number from 1 to `$splits`.

All elements end with a space since the function looks for `$split` and you have a space before each split. If you don't want to have the trailing whitespace then you can change the code to this:

```
$a[] = trim(substr($str, strpos($str, "$split{$i} ") + strlen("$split{$i} ")));
```

Also, notice that `strpos` looks for a space after the delimiter. Again, if you don't want the space then remove it from the string.

The reason I have used a function is that it will make it flexible for you in the future if you decide that you want to have four splits or change the delimiter.

Obviously, if you no longer want a numerically changing delimiter then the [`explode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) exists for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
-{1,2}((split1)|(split2)|(split3)) [\w|\s]+
```

Something like this? This will, in this case, create 3 arrays which all will have an array of elements of the same name in them. Hope this helps

Comment: [This `-{1,2}((split1)|(split2)|(split3)) [\w|\s]+` regex](https://regex101.com/r/PGR9W8/1) is the same as OP's - it matches all options, even duplicate ones.